# Generics 'is not identical to' error

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm playing around with using generics in Swift in order to create KVO-like functionality, but I'm getting this error and I just can't figure out why:

[image: error message]

This is all the code:

```
struct Observable<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T
    typealias SubscriptionType = Subscription<T>

    var value: ValueType {
        didSet {
            let event = ValueChangeEvent(oldValue, value)
            self.subscriptions.notify(event)
        }
    }

    var subscriptions = Subscriptions<SubscriptionType>()

    init(_ value: ValueType) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct ValueChangeEvent<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T

    let oldValue: ValueType
    let newValue: ValueType

    init(_ o: ValueType, _ n: ValueType) {
        oldValue = o
        newValue = n
    }
}

class Subscription<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T
    typealias HandlerType = (oldValue: ValueType, newValue: ValueType) -> ()

    let handler: HandlerType

    init(handler: HandlerType) {
        self.handler = handler
    }

    func notify(event: ValueChangeEvent<ValueType>) {
        self.handler(oldValue: event.oldValue, newValue: event.newValue)
    }
}

struct Subscriptions<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T
    typealias SubscriptionType = Subscription<T>

    private var subscriptions = Array<SubscriptionType>()

    mutating func add(handler: SubscriptionType.HandlerType) -> SubscriptionType {
        let subscription = Subscription(handler: handler)
        self.subscriptions.append(subscription)
        return subscription
    }

    mutating func remove(subscription: SubscriptionType) {
        var index = NSNotFound
        var i = 0
        for element in self.subscriptions as [SubscriptionType] {
            if element === subscription {
                index = i
                break
            }
            i++
        }

        if index != NSNotFound {
            self.subscriptions.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

    func notify(event: ValueChangeEvent<ValueType>) {
        for subscription in subscriptions {
           subscription.notify(event)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on what I see, it looks like the `subscriptions` property of `Observable<T>` is incorrectly defined:

```
var subscriptions = Subscriptions<SubscriptionType>()
```

whereas it should be:

```
var subscriptions = Subscriptions<ValueType>()
```

I didn't dig into the logic, so I cannot say if with that changes your code still works - if it doesn't, it's a good starting point for you to figure out what's wrong.